# Hierarchy problem and loop quantum gravity

Tags: string-theory, higgs, loop-quantum-gravity, fine-tuning

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy_problem#Finite_Groups.

Hierarchy problem can be **theoretically** solved using symmetry of certain bosonic string theory on the Leech lattice (though there is not even a single citation in that paragraph). So my question is this: Whether hierarchy problem is also addressed in LQG since both the theories (ST and LGQ) tries to address quantization of gravity.

This question might be wrong as well. As https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9710008 states that one cannot calculate mass of elementary particle in LQG and wikipedia article about hierarchy problem states that it ultimately boils down to discrepancy between Higgs boson mass and Planck mass. So above question may be ill-posed for LQG.

Comment: In string theory the Hierarchy problem is solved by Supersymmetry.